# Python3 NZEC Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

This piece of code is supposed to find account balance after withdraw from bank(fee=0.5).

```
wd,ac=raw_input().split(" ")
wd=int(wd)
ac=float(ac)
if(ac<wd):
    print(ac)
elif(wd%5==0):
    if(ac>wd+0.50):
        print(ac-wd-0.50)
    else:
        print(ac)
else:
    print(ac)
```

I got a `Runtime NZEC Error` while submitting on codechef. I am newbie and had searched for resolve and had used `split(" ")` in place of `int(input())`, which I had tried previously, but the problem still occurs.

Geeksforgeeks says:

> "In python, generally multiple inputs are separated by commas and we read them using `input()` or `int(input())`, but most of the online coding platforms while testing gives input separated by space and in those cases `int(input())` is not able to read the input properly and shows error like NZEC"

Given that I've tried to account for that... What is wrong with my code?

Comment: NZEC is not a useful error code. I'd recommend loading this up on a local Python installation and doing your debugging there. You'll get much more meaningful errors.

Comment: Can you give an example of an input?  I don't think this is really possible to debug without knowing what an example input would be.  For example, if you do `print(raw_input())`, what do you get?

Comment: Did you mean to use `raw_input` instead of `input` in line 1? I believe that `raw_input` is a python 2.x feature, and it was removed in python 3.

Comment: input- **30 120.00**
expected output- **89.50**
it works fine while running on local machine, but when submitting to codechef it says Runtime NZEC Error .

Comment: @DeepeshKumar On your local machine, would you mind typing `python -v` from the command line and tell us the result? I have a sneaking suspicion your local machine is using python 2, and codechef is on python 3.

Comment: have both python2 as well python3, and while running i am using python3.

Comment: Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2 as well 
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an error with your `raw_input` statement. Remember that, in python 3, `raw_input` doesn't exist any more. If you changed it from `raw_input` to `input`, then the code works just fine.

Comment: says **SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing** while using `input`

Comment: It works for me on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@JakobLovern1/AdventurousSoupyJuliabutterfly)

Comment: works fine when input is 30 120
but give error for 30 120.00

Comment: Well, then... I'm stumped. [You seem to have a bizarre tech issue.](https://xkcd.com/1586/)